# how to write cleaner if-else statements and prevent nesting?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements, coding-style

So I know that nesting code can get ugly very quickly. Therfore I looked up a way to prevent nesting an found out that you can do the following

```
if (user == null) return;

console.log('Deleting');
user.delete();
```

Instead of using curly brackets like that

```
if (user != null) {
    console.log('Deleting');
    user.delete();
}
```

However I can't really see how this is helpful when using an if-else statement. For example: I have this piece of code from my project that I would really like to write in a cleaner way than that. But I am struggling to figure out how this can be done.

```
           if (parseInt(year) == joinTime.getFullYear()) {
                if (parseInt(month) == joinTime.getMonth() + 1) {
                    if (parseInt(day) == joinTime.getDay()) {
                        channel.send(message);
                    } else {
                        comparison(day, hour, minute);
                    }
                } else {
                    comparison(day, hour, minute);
                }
            } else {
                comparison(day, hour, minute);
            }
```

Comment: `if (a && b && c) ... else ...`…?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style is in the eye of the beholder, but assuming you want cleaner code then something like this is what I would do:

```js
    const yearMatch = (parseInt(year) == joinTime.getFullYear());
    const monthMatch = (parseInt(month) == joinTime.getMonth() + 1);
    const dayMatch = (parseInt(day) == joinTime.getDay());
    
    if (yearMatch && monthMatch && dayMatch) {
        channel.send(message);
    } else {
        comparison(day, hour, minute);
    }
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about the additional `return` (and it doesn't break your logic):

```js
    const yearMatch = (parseInt(year) == joinTime.getFullYear());
    const monthMatch = (parseInt(month) == joinTime.getMonth() + 1);
    const dayMatch = (parseInt(day) == joinTime.getDay());

    if (yearMatch && monthMatch && dayMatch) return channel.send(message);
    
    comparison(day, hour, minute);
```

Of course, do change the variable names as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think dropping the curly brackets is the solution when working with nested if else statements. In this case I would try to limit the amount of statements used. You could transfor this code to:

```
if(parseInt(year) == joinTime.getFullYear() && parseInt(month) == joinTime.getMonth() + 1 && parseInt(day) == joinTime.getDay()){
     channel.send(message);
}
else {
    comparison(day, hour, minute);
}
```

Or you could use the parsed year, month and day to construct a date object en compare that to the joinTime.

Answer (score 2):

you can write this as below

```
if (
parseInt(year) == joinTime.getFullYear() &&
parseInt(month) == joinTime.getMonth() + 1 && 
parseInt(day) == joinTime.getDay()
) {
   channel.send(message);
} else {
   comparison(day, hour, minute);
}
```